# How would I correctly map my Enum Delivery status values from my Delivery Model to Delivery ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Currently, I'm having issues with saving the `Enum` values to my database because I'm not mapping correctly from my `ViewModel` to my `Model` and vise versa. The issue lies when I try to `Edit` an existing `Delivery`. It gets the `status`, but when I try to `save` it, it doesn't `save` the new `status`.

This line `delivery.status = model.Status;` does not work and I don't know if I should be setting the `Enum` in the `ViewModel` as well.

I'm quite stumped because I have no idea how to do this. I'm still a beginner so and I'm trying to wrap my head around this development, can anyone please suggest a solution or point me in the right direction?

View Model:

```
public enum Status
{
    Dispatched, Delayed, Delivered
}
public class DeliveryVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int DriverID { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    ....
    Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(id);
    // Initialize the view model
    DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM()
    {
        ID = delivery.DeliveryID,
        DriverID = delivery.DriverID,
        Status = model.Status; // this doesn't work
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeliveryVM model)
{

    // Get the data model based on the ID of the view model
    Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(model.ID);
    // Map the view model properties to the data model
    delivery.DriverID = model.DriverID;
    delivery.status = model.Status; // this doesn't work

   // Mark as modified and save
   ....
   return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = delivery.DeliveryID });
}
```

Model:

```
public enum Status
{
   Dispatched, Delayed, Delivered
}
public class Delivery
{
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Driver")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

View Code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="dropdown" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the error I get on this line `delivery.status = model.Status;`:

[image]

Comment: I can't see anywhere in `Edit` that you're setting `Status` on the model or the view model.

Comment: Is this the shortest question you could ask, or did you simply not read [ask]?

Comment: @CharlesMager, I'm not sure how to set using Enum? I've looked at various alternatives on stack, but they seem to complex for me to understand.

Comment: @mustang00, You need to stop dumping all your code in every question you ask. Almost all this is irrelevant to your issue. Just post the relevant code

Comment: @mustang00 - The site tour, particularly the link I refered to, explains why you should ask questions in a specific manner, and advises to ask questions that concentrate on the issue, and not boilerplate. Your question contains so much code that it can not be the minimim required to reproduce your problem. That makes it hard to read, hard to understand, hard to spot the actual problem and solution and generally decreaese motivation to try to help. In the end, you reduce your chances getting a good answer while wasting other users time in the process. (continued...)

Comment: If you did take the time to ask a more concise (read: better) question, it would be much easier to help you, and you'll be more satisfied.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've only posted, the `View Model` and `Model` of `Delivery` and the `Edit method` nothing more?

Comment: @mustang00, What do all those `DateTime` properties etc have to do with your issue. You need to take note of Amit's comments. No one wants to scroll through a lot of irrelevant code. Just reproduce the shortest code necessary to focus on your specific issue, and indicate the line of code causing the problem

Comment: Apologies @StephenMuecke, I've condensed the code in the question and tried to be more specific.

Comment: I will take your advice into account the next time I ask a question. Thank you @Amit

Comment: @mustang00 - no hard feelings. I'm happy you saw my comments helpful.

Comment: Still far too much code (and you missing the view code where you render the control for `Status`) and have not shown how you set the value of `Status` and the error it generates, but you have declared an `enum Status` in the data model and an `enum Status` in the view model - they are different types so you cannot make a direct mapping from one to the other

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I added the `View` code and I added the error I get when I try to map. I wasn't sure if I should  `enum Status` in the `ViewModel`. I tried removing it, and changing     `public Status Status { get; set; }` in the `ViewModel` to `public string Status { get; set; }` , but it still had an issue with this line `delivery.status = model.Status;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared 2 separate `enums` for `Status`, one in the assembly for you data model and one in the assembly for your view model. They are different types and cannot be converted from one to the other. You could have the view model refer to the `enum Status` in the data model assembly, or you can map between them using the `Enum.TryParse()` method, for example to map from the data model to the view model in the GET method

```
HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status status = HealthHabitat.ViewModels.Status.Dispatched;
Enum.TryParse(delivery.Status.ToString(), out status);
DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM()
{
    ID = delivery.DeliveryID,
    DriverID = delivery.DriverID,
    Status = status;
};
```

and then in the POST method, do it in reverse

```
HealthHabitat.Models.Status status = HealthHabitat.Models.Status.Dispatched;
Enum.TryParse(model.Status.ToString(), out status);
delivery.Status = status;
```

Comment: Do I continue using this line `delivery.status = model.Status;` in my POST method? Should it be changed or removed?

Comment: No you will need to do the same thing as I showed above but in reverse (I'll update answer in a moment)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most straightforward way make you ViewModel Status property either a string or an int and map to and from the Status in your controller... or in your data Select calls if you must as you are doing now.

If that not the issue as I don't see what you are doing in your view, in your Edit action method you don't update delivery.Status with the view model value anyhow that I can see..

```
Delivery delivery = db.Deliverys.Find(model.ID);
// Map the view model properties to the data model
delivery.DriverID = model.DriverID;
delivery.Dispatched_Date = model.Dispatched_Date;
delivery.Dispatched_Time = model.Dispatched_Time;
delivery.Delivered_Date = model.Delivered_Date;
delivery.Delivered_Time = model.Delivered_Time;
delivery.Delayed_Date = model.Delayed_Date;
delivery.Delayed_Time = model.Delayed_Time;
delivery.Comment = model.Comment;

//where is this?
delivery.Status = model.Status;//do a mapping from int or string if you change VM like i suggested
```

Comment: I've added that line `delivery.Status = model.Status;` but it says cannot implicitly convert string to status so I commented out in my code.

Comment: Use Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), model.Status)